Deleted synced SharePoint folder from File Explorer but still finding it on SharePoint Site
I created a synced SharePoint folder by clicking the “sync” button on the SharePoint site for that folder owned by my company. In File Explorer, this folder appeared in the navigation panel under my company OneDrive.
I deleted this folder in File Explorer by right-clicking and clicking “Delete”. I went on the company SharePoint site for that folder, where I was surprised to find that all its content still seemed to be there. I checked File Activity and and no deletions were recorded for this folder.
I thought that if you delete a synced SharePoint folder on your computer it will also be deleted remotely? Can anyone explain what happened? Thanks so much!

Deleting an online-only folder permanetly removes it from your pc without sending it to the recycle bin. This action simply stops the continued synchronization of this Library.

But if you add or delete files or subfolders under this folder, it will be synchronized to SharePoint.

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.
